# Why error messages are different?

Tags: perl

I have two programs:

```
#line 1 "DB::eval"
234asd

perl < tmp.pl
Bareword found where operator expected at DB::eval line 1, near "234asd"
    (Missing operator before asd?)
syntax error at DB::eval line 2, near "234asd
"
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```

and second:

```
$str =  <<CODE;
#line 1 "DB::eval"
234asd
CODE
eval $str;
print $@;

perl < tmp.pl
Bareword found where operator expected at DB::eval line 1, near "#line 1 "DB::eval"
234asd"
    (Missing operator before asd?)
syntax error at DB::eval line 2, near "#line 1 "DB::eval"
234asd

"
```

Why in second case I got extra text in error message: `#line 1 "DB::eval"`? I do not expect it.

Also in second case I do not expect extra new line. I expect:

```
234asd
"
```

Instead of:

```
234asd

"
```

Comment: Is this a rhetorical question? If so, use `perlbug` instead of StackOverflow. If not, what more than "because `perl` isn't `eval`" do you want?

Comment: @ikegami do you think the porters will appreciate this as a core bug? I think they have just as little sense of humor as we do. :)

Comment: Yes, inconsistencies such as this one would likely be considered a bug. I don't know why you bring up sense of humour.

Comment: @ikegami https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=131650

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call that a bug, just implementation dependent behavior.

The 2nd heredoc variant just includes more context.
Nobody guarantees that heredoc'd evals behave the same as direct scripts.

p5p agreed with me, Zefram didn't call it a bug, and SawyerX rejected it.